# Is it a very common and recognized way to pronounce the word "opposite" /ˈɑː.pə.sɪt/?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, american-accent

Cambridge Dictionary gives an IPA /ˈɑː.pə.zɪt/ for the word "opposite", which totally fits with what I know.

This American kindergarten teacher in the YouTube video titled: [**Antonym Rap**: Reviewing Words with Opposite Meanings](https://youtu.be/HFAFLm29pTg?list=PL16BB4ACF5B10B893&t=28) is pronouncing *opposite* /ˈɑː.pə.sɪt/, the difference is the pronunciation of "s" in the word.

Is it a very common and recognized way to pronounce the word "opposite"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think /ˈɑpəsɪt/ is not extremely uncommon, although it's a little hard for me to find sources that mention it. When I (an American English speaker) read your question, I pronounced the word both ways, and thought that while I would say it with /z/ by default, the pronunciation with /s/ doesn't sound completely impossible or unnatural to me.

The Oxford English Dictionary entry implies that American English speakers are more likely than British English speakers to use /z/, in that it gives the following list of pronunciations:

> Brit. /ˈɒpəzɪt/, /ˈɒpəsɪt/, U.S. /ˈɑpəzət/

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/opposite) suggests that the number of syllables in the word varies along with the consonant used at the start of the last syllable, but I don't think that's a complete description of the pronunciations used. I think the word is not heard with two syllables as often as it is heard with an /s/ sound.

> \ ˈä-pə-zət  , ˈäp-sət \

Comment: I have no difficulty in understanding the pronunciation of *opposite* used in the video. Instead I find the children's teacher pronunciation of "dull" and "wide" to be more problematic for me!